# HOW-TO: Angular library divided in independent feature sub libraries

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-library, ng-packagr

I am currently developing an Angular library (in *Angular v* **8.1.0**) and wondering how is it possible to have it *"split in different sub-libraries"*?

For example, Angular (`@angular`) is split somehow in different "parts" like:

- `@angular/common`
- `@angular/core`
- `@angular/forms`
- etc.

and for instance, `@angular/common` has different sub-directories available to import from:

- `@angular/common/http`
- `@angular/common/locale`
- `@angular/common/testing`

I am wondering how to do this kind of structuring in my own Angular library to keep different context elements independent one of each other. Let's say my library is called `cool-lib` and there are different feature modules which contain their own services/components/etc: `common`, `featureA`, `featureB`.

I would like to achieve something like this:

```js
import { CommonService } from 'cool-lib/common';
import { FeatAComponent, FeatAService } from 'cool-lib/feature-a';
import { FeatBModule } from 'cool-lib/feature-b';
```

instead of having:

```js
import { 
  CommonService, 
  FeatAComponent, 
  FeatAService,
  FeatBModule
} from 'cool-lib';
```

and it even also would be nice to be able to independently bump version numbers of the different feature modules or simply having installed only those that are going to be needed without having to install the whole libary (let's say I only need `featureA`).

For example, having on my **package.json**:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "cool-lib/common": "1.0.0",
    "cool-lib/feature-a": "1.0.0",
    "cool-lib/feature-b": "1.3.0"
  }
}
```

or just:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "cool-lib/feature-a": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

instead of:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "cool-lib": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

I have read a lot about creating Angular libraries so far, but couldn't find this specific use case as all of them cover just the very basics of creating and publishing them on npm... so any help on this is very welcomed!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Angular already supports multiple *sub-libraries* out of the box.

The default project structure contains an *"app"* application that is a regular Angular project, and then you add additional *sub-libraries* that are Angular Library projects. There are placed in the `library` sub-folder.

A single Angular project can contain multiple *sub-library* projects.

Each *sub-library* project can be published as a separate npm package, because they have their own `package.json` file.

npm supports something called [scoped](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-scopes) package names. Which allows you to name a package as `@angular/core` where `@angular` is the scope of the package.

You can add a scoped library to your current Angular project like this.

```
ng generate library @my-scope/my-library
```

When you import from a scoped project it must be prefixed with the scope.

For example;

```js
import { CommonService } from '@cool-lib/common';
import { FeatAComponent, FeatAService } from '@cool-lib/feature-a';
import { FeatBModule } from '@cool-lib/feature-b';
```

In the above, the name `@cool-lib` is the scope and `common` is the name of the npm package.

Using scopes lets you do two basic things (as far as I'm aware).

1. prevents name collision with other packages, for example `@cool-lib/animations` will not collide with `@angular/animations`
2. organizes packages into `node_modules/@cool-lib`